# Yup validation decimal number

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

Thank you in advance,
I'm using yup in my React project to validate my schema, problem is in field called "price":

```
price: Yup.number().required("Required"),
```

when I add value with comma like `45,89` yup throw me an error that price must be a number. I'm like that float with comma is same like float with dot. 
Is there a way to take current value from validation schema and replace it? like `current.replace(",",".")`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `typeError(message: string): Schema`
to define an error message for failed type checks. The `${value}` and `${type}` interpolation can be used in the message argument.